# Azure ML Experiment Scheduling - No web service

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I want to schedule an Azure ML experiment to run everyday without creating a web service. Is that possible. Is there no scheduler in Azure ML itself.

I basically import the latest data from Azuresql and then export the predictions again into AzureSql.

Answer (score 0):

try using powershell - https://github.com/hning86/azuremlps and use powershell cmdlets for scheduling it